# What are the side effects of disabling Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler?

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, media-library, tracking

Our load tests have shown that the `Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler` reduces load time of media assets by a certain factor.

If we were to disable this handler, what functionality would we lose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler` is responsible for tracking all media requests and storing that information in the xDB.

If you look at the `OnMediaRequest` method, in there it gets the site context and tracker information and then tracks any page events or goals etc... that are associated with that media item/type.

If you disable that handler, it will prevent any tracking data from being written on media requests.

Comment: Any idea how to disable only the pageviews for media? My media downloads are appearing as pageviews with 0 seconds. I need them to only appear as a page event or goal.

Comment: @NotAnotherCliche if you have another question, please don't tag it on in a comment, open another question. Thanks

Comment: Sure, here it is. Thank you! https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/23670/6439