# Why are my downloads (PDF, DOC) being tracked as pageviews in Experience Profile?

Tags: experience-analytics, experience-profile

Our downloads (PDF, DOC, etc) are being tracked as pageviews in Experience Profile. This means our totals and calculations involving pageviews are incorrect. Downloads shouldn't be considered a pageview; only the page from which the download was clicked should count as a pageview.

How can we stop analytics from incorrectly tracking downloaded documents as pageviews?

The download still needs to track as a download event (or any other event we choose).

[image: Media resource tracking]

Thank you in advance.